# jolt specification for a JSON conversion

Tags: json, jolt

Need help with a JOLT specification for converting the JSON from the shared input format to the expected format.

Input JSON:

```
{
  "DataModel": {
    "Header": {
      "TMS_ID": "2030617701",
      "PROCESS_CD": "WvWellHeader",
      "BATCH_ID": "30772",
      "RECORD_COUNT": "1",
      "SOURCE_SYSTEM": "WELLVIEW",
      "SOURCE_RECORD_ID": "2030617701",
      "TARGET_SYSTEM": "EDW",
      "TRANSACTION_TYPE": "NEW",
      "SOURCE_CREATE_DATE": "2017-03-29T10:18:00-05:00",
      "KEY": {
        "ELEMENT_NAME": "KEY_PAIRS",
        "ELEMENT_VALUE": "WvWellHeader?Idrec=7052A964B7EB45D684CC3849E3ED5848"
      },
      "DELETE_FL": "N"
    },
    "Data": "H4sIAAAAAAAAA42UXW+bMBSGr7dfYWnSAA=="
  }
}
```

**Expected JSON**

```
{
    "TMS_ID" :"2030617701",
    "PROCESS_CD" :"WvWellHeader",
    "BATCH_ID" :"30772",
    "SOURCE_SYSTEM" :"WELLVIEW",
    "SOURCE_RECORD_ID" :"2030617701",
    "ELEMENT_VALUE" :"WvWellHeader?Idrec=7052A964B7EB45D684CC3849E3ED5848",
    "DELETE_FL" :"N",
    "Data" : "HH4sIAAAAAAAAA42UXW+bMBSGr7dfYWnSAA=="
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spec to get you started

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DataModel": {
        "Header": {
          "TMS_ID": "TMS_ID",
          "KEY": {
            "ELEMENT_VALUE": "ELEMENT_VALUE"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Produces

```
{
  "TMS_ID" : "2030617701",
  "ELEMENT_VALUE" : "WvWellHeader?Idrec=7052A964B7EB45D684CC3849E3ED5848"
}
```

Run it at http://jolt-demo.appspot.com and read / play with the examples.

Comment: Thank you Milo! Your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Here is the final output I came up with.

[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "DataModel": {
        "Header": {
          "TMS_ID": "TMS_ID",
          "PROCESS_CD": "PROCESS_CD",
          "BATCH_ID": "BATCH_ID",
          "SOURCE_SYSTEM": "SOURCE_SYSTEM",
          "SOURCE_RECORD_ID": "SOURCE_RECORD_ID",
          "KEY": {
            "ELEMENT_VALUE": "ELEMENT_VALUE"
          },
          "DELETE_FL": "DELETE_FL"
        },
        "Data": "Data"
      }
    }
  }
]